# Ubuntu 12.04: WiFi not working after suspension

Tags: 12.04, wireless

here is my configuration:
- S.O.: Ubuntu 12.04
- Kernel: 3.5.0-25
- Laptop: Sony Vaio VGN-FZ21E
- WiFi car: Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan]
- driver: iwl3945

After suspension my WiFi isn't working, even restarting network or reloading modules. It seems simply that the card is switched off and Ubuntu cannot communicate with it.
I thought this as I had a look into */var/log/syslog* and I've found this:

```
Mar 11 17:33:25 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5225.608061] sky2 0000:08:00.0: eth0: disabling interface
Mar 11 17:33:25 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5225.619189] sky2 0000:08:00.0: eth0: enabling interface
Mar 11 17:33:25 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5225.619706] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Mar 11 17:33:26 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5226.637161] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:26 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5226.637171] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:26 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5226.764525] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:26 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5226.764531] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:26 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5226.891926] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:26 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5226.891932] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:26 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5227.019321] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:26 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5227.019326] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:26 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5227.146696] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:26 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5227.146701] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:26 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5227.147044] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts.
Mar 11 17:33:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5231.965726] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5231.965735] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5232.093091] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5232.093097] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5232.220442] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5232.220447] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:32 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5232.347782] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:32 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5232.347787] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:32 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5232.475196] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:32 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5232.475201] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:32 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5232.475555] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts.
Mar 11 17:33:36 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5236.981027] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:36 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5236.981040] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:36 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5237.111258] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:36 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5237.111267] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:37 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5237.241510] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:37 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5237.241517] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:37 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5237.371699] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:37 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5237.371706] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:37 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5237.501865] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:37 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5237.501873] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:37 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5237.502352] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts.
Mar 11 17:33:44 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5245.165294] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:44 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5245.165302] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:45 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5245.292676] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:45 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5245.292681] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:45 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5245.420165] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:45 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5245.420171] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:45 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5245.547518] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:45 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5245.547523] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:45 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5245.675049] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: BSM uCode verification failed at addr 0x00003800+0 (of 900), is 0xffffffff, s/b 0xf802020
Mar 11 17:33:45 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5245.675054] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to set up bootstrap uCode: -5
Mar 11 17:33:45 pablo-laptop kernel: [ 5245.675425] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to initialize device after 5 attempts.
```

After upgrading the kernel to 3.5.0-25, i noticed a new module named **iwlwifi**, which is also present in syslog and he seems to have a dialog with wireless card:

```
Mar 12 09:48:16 pablo-laptop kernel: [  209.569037] iwlwifi: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
Mar 12 09:48:16 pablo-laptop kernel: [  209.569044] iwlwifi: Copyright(c) 2003-2012 Intel Corporation
Mar 12 09:49:05 pablo-laptop kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
```

Any idea ?!

> **2013.03.12**

Here is the output of **lspci -nn | grep 0280**:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
```

Command **ls /etc/modprobe.d | grep iwl** gave anything....

> **2013.03.13**

iwlwifi was not present in /etc/modules, and was successfully added to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.

I tried to suspend and resume for three times, but the 4th time the problem occurred.

p.s. The same problem happened with Kernel 3.2, where iwlwifi was not present.

**IMPORTANT: Upgrade Manager is advising me to install 'network management framework (common files for wifi and mobile)' and 'network management framework(GNOME dialogs for wifi and mobile)'. Should I install them? What do they do exaclty? Can affect my problem ?**

> **2013.03.14**

Added the following line in file **/etc/pm/config.d/config**

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="iwl3945"
```

After some successfull tests, the problem occurred with new error messagges in Syslog:

```
iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: bad EEPROM signature,EEPROM_GP=0x00000007
iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: EEPROM not found, EEPROM_GP=0xffffffff
iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to init EEPROM
iwl3945: probe of 0000:06:00.0 failed with error -2
```

Then I did another test, which was successfull, and these are the messages in syslog:

```
cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 23 802.11a channels
iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
Registered led device: phy0-led
cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.32.2.9
```

> **2013.03.18**

Problem occurred again, and I've noticed a trace called in Syslog:

```
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008] Pid: 3535, comm: modprobe Tainted: P           O 3.5.0-25-generic #39~precise1-Ubuntu
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008] Call Trace:
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c1045c62>] warn_slowpath_common+0x72/0xa0
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<f887d986>] ? _il_grab_nic_access+0x96/0xa0 [iwlegacy]
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<f887d986>] ? _il_grab_nic_access+0x96/0xa0 [iwlegacy]
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c1045d33>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x33/0x40
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<f887d986>] _il_grab_nic_access+0x96/0xa0 [iwlegacy]
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<f887dac2>] il_wr_prph+0x32/0x90 [iwlegacy]
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<f887dc79>] il_apm_init+0x159/0x1d0 [iwlegacy]
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<f88c44b5>] il3945_apm_init+0x15/0x130 [iwl3945]
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<f887f085>] il_eeprom_init+0x45/0x1b0 [iwlegacy]
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c12f2daa>] ? pci_bus_write_config_byte+0x5a/0x70
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<f88c2e9d>] il3945_pci_probe+0x19d/0x4b0 [iwl3945]
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c13bdbe5>] ? pm_runtime_enable+0x45/0x70
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c12fa4b7>] local_pci_probe+0x47/0xb0
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c12fba08>] pci_device_probe+0x68/0x90
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c11b3077>] ? sysfs_create_link+0x17/0x20
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c13b5201>] really_probe+0x51/0x1c0
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c13bf099>] ? pm_runtime_barrier+0x49/0xb0
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c13b54aa>] driver_probe_device+0x3a/0x60
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c13b5561>] __driver_attach+0x91/0xa0
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c13b54d0>] ? driver_probe_device+0x60/0x60
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c13b3c12>] bus_for_each_dev+0x42/0x70
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c13b4ee1>] driver_attach+0x21/0x30
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c13b54d0>] ? driver_probe_device+0x60/0x60
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c13b4b47>] bus_add_driver+0x187/0x260
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c12fba30>] ? pci_device_probe+0x90/0x90
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c13b5a16>] driver_register+0x66/0x110
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c12fb7d2>] __pci_register_driver+0x42/0xa0
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<f8853050>] il3945_init+0x50/0x1000 [iwl3945]
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c103b80f>] ? set_memory_nx+0x5f/0x70
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c1003034>] do_one_initcall+0x34/0x170
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<f8853000>] ? 0xf8852fff
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c10a544d>] sys_init_module+0xad/0x210
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c11519d3>] ? sys_close+0x73/0xc0
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008]  [<c15ea8df>] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.564008] ---[ end trace f7ec9f13abaf4b1b ]---
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.692242] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: bad EEPROM signature,EEPROM_GP=0x00000007
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.692249] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: EEPROM not found, EEPROM_GP=0xffffffff
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.692283] iwl3945 0000:06:00.0: Unable to init EEPROM
Mar 18 09:39:31 pablo-laptop kernel: [18048.692467] iwl3945: probe of 0000:06:00.0 failed with error -2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Also: ls /etc/modprobe.d | grep iwl

Comment: Did it, as I wrote ls /etc/modprobe.d | grep iwl gave no results.

Comment: 2013.03.13: SORRY TO INFORM YOU THAT THE PROBLEM STILL PERSISTS.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: After updating to Ubuntu 14.04 the problem disappeared. Maybe something change in the module, or the module has changed.
Maybe it's important that someone have a look at that, as the 12.04 LTS is supported till 2017.

Comment: I'm having exactly this problem on 14.04, BOTH with wired and wireless networking.

Comment: @VictorSergienko I had similar issues with my wifi due to bluetooth. I fixed them by turning off bluetooth. This also fixed my ethernet issues. I have no idea why this would happen. Maybe the Gods are angry with Mark Shuttleworth or something.

Comment: This is happening again on 16.4, after having been fixed on 15.10.  Not good.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a technique that sometimes works:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

Add a single line:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="iwl3945"
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. Reboot, suspend and let us have your report.

Comment: Since now I've tested many times in different situations, like suspend leaving some programs running and not, or suspend and immediately remume, or resume after hours. All tests went ok, I'll let you know something more precise during next days !

Comment: Great news. I look forward to your success!

Comment: Sorry to inform you that the problem occurred again. I edited the main answer with syslog messages (when it works and when it don't)

Comment: I have Googled this extensively: EEPROM not found, EEPROM_GP=0xffffffff and, so far, I have found no solution. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you chili. I also did that research over the net, finding anything interesting.
Anyway, I can say the problem is solved now as 99% of the times NOW suspension works fine, after I added SUSPEND_MODULES="iwl3945" to /etc/pm/config.d/config file !

Answer (score 0):

The driver iwl3945 is correct for your device; iwlwifi is not. Let's see why it's loading and stop it. Please do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modules
```

If iwlwifi is in there, remove it. Proofread, save and close gedit. Now do:

```
sudo su
echo "blacklist iwlwifi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Now reboot and tell us how it's working.

Comment: SORRY TO INFORM YOU THAT THE PROBLEM STILL PERSISTS.

Comment: Since now, anyway, most of the times IT WORKS ! But I don't know why and how to reproduce the problem. Are there any kind of tests I may do when problem occurs ?

Comment: The problem that it doesn't resume from suspend or that dmesg throws lots of errors?

Comment: The problem (now) is that most of the times works, but sometimes not. When it does not work, I find a lot of errors in Syslog (as I reported first)

Answer (score 0):

until this bug is fixed what I use best is this:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

type it in terminal after suspension

I still haven't tried it enough times to be sure that it would work everytime but I hope it does

Answer (score 0):

unistall the NetworkManager and install wicd-gtk try with that .

sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk

make sure uninstall the NM.

if not worked check

rfkill

then ublock all

again workk on it